# does improved euler method fail when we increase step size?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does improved Euler method fail when we increase step size?meaning does it give worse answer than standard Euler method when our step size is big?

Comment: What did you try? Write down the steps of the methods for $y'=-y$ and check for contraction or non-contraction of the iteration map.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do the first step. For the ODE $y'=-y$, for which the solution is monotically decreasing towards $0$, the transition from $y_0$ to $y_1$ with step size $h$ is

**Euler forward**

$y_1=y_0+hf(y_0)=(1-h)y_0$ which becomes unstable for $h\ge 2$.

**Improved Euler**
$$
y_1=y_0+h·f(y_0+h/2·f(y_0))=y_0-h·(y_0-h/2·y_0)=(1-h+h^2/2)·y_0
$$
Now explore when $|1-h+h^2/2|\ge 1$